# Datetimeoffset doesn't bind from http request into my view model in .Net Core 6

Tags: api, .net-core

I have a web API in .Net Core 6.

This is my view model:

```
public class SetMarkingInvestmenViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public decimal Investment { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTimeOffset StartPeriod { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my controller:

```
 [HttpPost("set-investment")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SetMarketingInvestment(SetMarkingInvestmenViewModel model)
        {
            var dto = _mapper.Map<MarketingHistoryDto>(model);
            var ret = await _marketingStatisticsService.CreateOrUpdateHistoryAsync(User.GetUserId(), dto);

            if (ret == null)
                return BadRequest("STARTPERIOD_EXISTS");

            if (ret.MarketingHistoryId != null)
                return NoContent();

            return BadRequest();
        }
```

I simply send a very basic query with Swagger :

curl -X POST "http://localhost:5000/api/market/set-investment" -H  "accept: */*" -H  "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxx" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{"investment":750,"startPeriod":"2023-05-12T15:52:41.009Z"}"

As a result I have my investment but my StartPeriod doesn't have offset (12/05/2023 15:52:41 +00:00).

Does anybody have an idea ? please ...

Answer (score 0):

That’s because you have `Z` in the end of serialized value, and `Z` means zero UTC offset.

You can read more about it here - [time offsets in ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC))